# Endless compilation loop with pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

I`m tring to compile se following document:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
    \pgfplotstabletypeset
        [
        every head row/.style{before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style{after row=\bottomrule},
        columns/Fruit/.style={string type},
        columns/Animal/.style={string type}
        ]
        {   
            Number Fruit Animal
            1.23456 Banana Dog
            2.871 Orange Cat
            3.141592 Apple Bear
        } % A file can be called here too 

\end{document}
```

However, the compilation goes into an infinite loop and does not generate errors. I'm using miktex with texstudio. I also tried overleaf, resulting in the same problem.

The problem seems to be related to the lines:

```
every head row/.style{before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style{after row=\bottomrule},
```

When commenting on these lines, the code works, but it is impossible to insert the dividers (`\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot the `=` after the first two `/.style` handlers.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
        columns/Fruit/.style={string type},
        columns/Animal/.style={string type}
        ]{   
            Number Fruit Animal
            1.23456 Banana Dog
            2.871 Orange Cat
            3.141592 Apple Bear
        } 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: :) I lost an entire afternoon with this problem. What a lack of attention. Thank you very much!